# Haxe flash API -- how to get/set the the flash display size?

Tags: flash, size, compilation, haxe

How do i get and set the size in pixels that the flash file's drawing output is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can only get but not set.

```
flash.Lib.current.stage.stageWidth
flash.Lib.current.stage.stageHeight
```